# How to redirect back to same page (the page he is already in) if someone manually try to visit different url of the site in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I don't want a user to enter a particular page if he is not required to. How can I stop a user from visiting the page if he manually type url in browser. What should I use , I am new to angularjs , idk if this is very silly question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to validate the user with a token of some sort.

Comment: isn't there any simpler method?

Comment: How are you going to know who can and cannot view the page?

Comment: if user is logged in he should not see login page again!! for authentication I used a function with boolean passed in.  I stored boolean value inside localStorage to call it even on refresh. When I open login page from url after user logs in , it is showing a blank page which I don't want.

Comment: Which router are you using? `ngRoute` or `ui-route`?

Comment: I am  using ngRoute

Answer (score 0):

Import router from @angular/router
In your component constructor check if authentication fails then go to link which you want. below is a simplest example of this procedure.

```
   //other imports
   import {Router} from '@angular/router';
   @Component({
          //your components html, selector,providers, directives
   })

   export class MyComponent{

  constructor(router:Router){
        //set this signed in in local storage when your user signs in successfully
        if(window.localStorage.getItem('signedIn')=="false")
        {
            //route wherever you want to
            router.navigate(['']);
        }
    }

  }
```